# Paste text with the order of directory

Tags: linux, bash, paste

I have a directory with 50 subdirectories that looks like this:

```
DIR -
     | dir1
     | dir2
     | dir...
     | dir49
     | dir50
```

Within each subdirectory, I have the two files with the same name

```
dir1 -
      |fileA.tsv
      |fileB.tsv
```

Now I want to paste `dir*/fileA.tsv` column wise; which can be achieved with

```
paste -d "\t" dir*/fileA.tsv > fileA_All.tsv
```

But the issue is the pasting order is wrong: it seems it’s pasting with this order:

```
dir1/fileA.tsv
dir10/fileA.tsv
dir11/fileA.tsv
...
```

Is there an approach to paste files with numerical order?

Comment: `paste dir{1..50}/fileA.tsv`?

Comment: @oguzismail indeed that's a great solution!!!

Comment: "directory" vs "folder" is a bit of a pet-peeve of mine (wtf is a "folder"?  In the real world, my folders are containers that hold exactly one file, so why did anyone ever think it was a good idea to use the word "folder" to describe an object that contains a list of names?) but....since the word "directory" is used everywhere in the question, and the directories are sensibly named "dir*", why does the word "folder" appear in the title?

Comment: @WilliamPursell okay thanks for the suggestion - will modify it.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
# Lists all dirs on separate lines.
printf "%s\n" dir*/fileA.tsv |
# This is HAHA-tricky. The separator is _the letter_ 'r'.
# We sort using the _second field_ numerically.
sort -tr -k2n |
xargs -d '\n' paste -d '\t' > fileA_All.tsv
```

To be pro, use zero separated streams: `printf "%s\0" ... sort -z ... xargs -0`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
paste dir{?,??}/fileA.tsv >fileA_All.tsv
```

`dir{?,??}` will expand first single digit directories and then two-digit ones (with `dir` prefix).